# Django test error

Tags: django, django-testing

When running `python manage.py test myapp2`, I get this error:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Problem installing fixture '... project folder .../mymainapp/fixtures/initial_data.yaml': Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "... project folder .../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 196, in handle
    obj.save(using=using)
  File "... project folder .../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 165, in save
    models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True)
  File "... project folder .../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 524, in save_base
    manager.using(using).filter(pk=pk_val).exists())):
  File "... project folder .../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 565, in exists
    return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
  File "... project folder .../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 441, in has_results
    return bool(compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE))
  File "... project folder .../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 818, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "... project folder .../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 52, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
DatabaseError: Could not load myapp2.table2(pk=1): relation "myapp2_table2" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "myapp2_table2" WHERE "myapp2...
                               ^
```

However, all of the actual tests run fine, so it appears the fixture is indeed getting successfully installed. I can also successfully install those fixtures when running South migrations.

What can I do to fix this error, even though it doesn't seem to affect anything? It seems to have occurred only after I hand-crafted a South migration.

Comment: Do you have separate database for two apps?

Comment: @AamirAdnan no, `myapp2` is an app I created for `mymainapp`. They reside within the same `mymainapp` folder and use the same database.